# FillRectangle on button Click into the form

Tags: c#, onclick, fill

I want to draw(Fill) a rectangle in to my form when I click on the button. But I can't manage to make it work and dont know what is wrong.

```
        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;  //verklaart naar object Graphics
        Vierkant vierkant = new Vierkant();
    }

    private void vierkant_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Cyan);
        g.FillRectangle(myBrush, 20, 20, 50, 50);
    }
```

Comment: Shall the drawing persist or not? Meaning: Shall it still be there after eg a Resize or maximize etc? Also: What is a Vierkant? To ake it 'work' without persisting you need to insert `using (Graphics g = this.CreateGrapgics)` before the `g.FillRectangle`. To make it persist you must move the `g.FillRectangle` to the Paint event and probably set a flag in the click and call this.Invalidate();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shall the drawing persist or not? Meaning: Shall it still be there after eg a Resize or maximize etc? Also: What is a Vierkant?

To make it persist you can use code like this:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (paintIt)
    using( SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Cyan) )
           e.Graphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, 20, 20, 50, 50);

}

bool paintIt = false;

private void vierkant_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    paintIt = true;
    this.Invalidate();

    // ?? what is this supposed to do or be??
    // Vierkant vierkant = new Vierkant();
}
```

This will work if both events are hooked up. For more interesting drawings you will need to store more than a bool flag but Lists of a drawAction class you need to invent which will include the shapes, its data, brushes etc..

If you replace `paintIt = true;` by `paintIt = !paintIt;` the Rectangle will appear and disappear on each click..